# GetWindowTextLength and GetClassName reusable class failed on new project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, pinvoke, user32

I run into a very strange behaviour in one of my solutions and I need help to solve this.
I use C# on Visual Studio 2015.

I have an Class library project, which has the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern long GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, long nMaxCount);

string getHWNDCaption(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("getHWNDCaption: Invalid pointer!");
    string caption = "";
    StringBuilder windowText = null;
    try
    {
        int max_length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
        windowText = new StringBuilder("", max_length + 50);
        GetWindowText(hwnd, windowText, max_length + 2);
    .....

string getHWNDClassName(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("ExternalWindowsInfo not initiated!");
    string className = "";
    StringBuilder classText = null;
    try
    {
        int cls_max_length = 1000;
        classText = new StringBuilder("", cls_max_length + 5);
        GetClassName(hwnd, classText, cls_max_length + 2);
    .......
```

In an old windows forms project I execute those functions and they return the needed data.

I tried to add new windows form project to the same solution and on execution of the same functions I receive the following error, which I cannot overrun:

```
 A call to PInvoke function ...::GetWindowTextLength' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
```

As I use the same code I believe it is something in the project definition, but cannot find out what.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I suspect `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` should be omitted or changed to `StdCall`. I also suspect that the working program is running as x86 and the failing one as x64.

Comment: Changing it to StdCall does not change the behaviour, i.e. it still crashes.
Both are using "Any CPU", what exactly you mean?

Comment: I mean that the calling convention should be `CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall` (or omitted altogether) for both those methods.

Comment: Many WinApi interop function declarations [are available online](https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindowTextLength).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have run around a bit more and thanks to [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) who give a clue:

1. I keep the CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl
2. I forced the project to use platform x64 (actually unchecking "Prefer 32-bit" was OK, but I ant to be sure) in Project properties -> Build.

Thanks!

Comment: Using x64 is an ugly hammer, get these declarations right instead of ignoring the problem.  The GetClassName declaration is wrong as well, not long but int. Watch out for old VB6 declarations, Long was the 32-bit integer type in that language.